# How can I have ColdFusion tags in a variable and have them evaluated?

Tags: coldfusion

I've get a variable that can contain a CF custom tag. E.g.

```
<cfset a = '<model:sparkline id="1"/>'/>
```

And I'd like that to be evaluated into HTML and outputted. Not sure how/if I can do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I force evaluation of a cfif stored in a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4494166/how-do-i-force-evaluation-of-a-cfif-stored-in-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sean Coyne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/151136/sean-coyne)'s answer is the correct one, provided the import is included within the same context as the cfsavecontent tag:

```
<cfimport taglib="./tags" prefix="model">

<cfsavecontent variable="a">
    <model:sparkline id="1" />
</cfsavecontent>

<cfoutput>#a#</cfoutput>
```

Will result in the dynamically evaluated output of the sparkline customtag.

Comment: I'm confused, the question you link to has examples of how it can be done.

Comment: That answer is a two-step process, which is 1) generate the dynamically created CFML and write it to disk, 2) execute it as its own page. That question (and this one) ask if can be dynamically evaluated and output atomically--it cannot. Can you dynamically create CF code? Yes. Can you output the result? Yes. Can you dynamically create CF code and output its result? No...they must be done in two separate processes: one to create, and one to execute.

Comment: Neither question asks for a one-step solution?

Comment: I butchered my original test yesterday (and thus, my answer). Sean Coyne's is correct.

Comment: But hang on... Sean's answer doesn't answer the question being asked!  The question being asked is "if I have some code in a variable, how can I execute that code?".  What Sean's answering is "how can I execute some code and put it in a variable".  Which is kinda the *opposite* of what's being asked.

Comment: @AdamCameron Re: Sean Coyne's answer, if the cfsavecontent method is used to set the variable 'a', then 'a' can be properly output as the evaluation of the the customtag's execution, which is how I read the question, so yes, in that sense he described how to set the variable, just not how to output its execution--I ammended my answer to hopefully provide that clarity and still point out that he was correct when I botched my initial assessment.

Answer (score 2):

Can you modify the custom tag?  If so you can use the `caller` scope to set a variable in the calling page.  So inside the custom tag you could do `<cfset caller.a = "whatever" />` and that will set the value in the calling page's `variables` scope.

If you don't want to modify the custom tag, then you can use `<cfsavecontent>` to save the output to a variable. Example:

```
<cfsavecontent variable="a">
    <model:sparkline id="1" />
</cfsavecontent>
```

Comment: Clever, I never tried that around a Custom Tag. Still unclear what he is attempting however, your solution is like using a custom tag as a function, why not just use a function. Or why not just let the custom tag do the output.

Comment: This doesn't work--the literal string is saved to 'a' and output, and what he wants is the dynamically evaluated content.

Comment: Shawn, this *does* work (i.e. evaluates the content when template is executed) if there is a `<cfimport prefix="model" taglib="/path/to/tags" />` in the same file.

Comment: (What it can't be used for is inserting `a` into a database, then having the text selected and then executed as CFML; that can only be done by writing to a file and cfincluding, or by using [OpenBD's `render` function](http://wiki.openbluedragon.org/wiki/index.php/Render()).)

Comment: @DaleFraser he wants to capture the HTML output of the custom tag in a variable which is exactly what cfsavecontent is for.

Comment: @ShawnHolmes this does work, as Peter pointed out if you have a cfimport for the tag library.  There are 3 ways go call CF custom tags, the cf_ syntax, using cfmodule, or using cfimport with a prefix as he is doing in his example.  The code in the custom tag will do its work, output its HTML which cfsavecontent would store in a variable.  I didn't get the impression that he wanted to dynamically evaluate code found in a string, but perhaps I am wrong and that is what he wants.

Comment: @Peter, You cannot dynamically create and evaluate code at runtime, period. The answer below this one is exactly the same. You can output the explicit tag, which will result in the output of <model:sparkline id="1" />, but that is not what he wants...he wants the dynamically evaluated result of that tag. Whatever <model:sparkline id="1" /> produces as an output is what he wants...and it cannot be decided dynamically and then executed. Including the <cfimport> tag or not doesn't decide this. I encourage you to go back and try again.

Comment: I've uploaded a test case to my site at www.wowlemmings.com/files/sandbox.rar, if you can make line #9 in tagtest.cfm work, I'll retract my comments here.

Comment: If the goal is to put the results of executing `<model:sparkline id="1" />` into a variable, then `cfsavecontent` can do this.

If the variable has already been pre-set, the code needs to be written to a file and included in order to be executed.

In both cases, the `cfimport` tag needs to have been included in the compiled code for `<model:... />` to be treated as a custom tag (rather than just text) by the compiler.

Comment: I ran through multiple tests with Coyne's answer yesterday and none worked...and now they all do. I concede, have voted his up. Be certain that the cfimport tag exists in the page that the <cfsavecontent> is called in, as noted by Peter.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to OUTPUT the code and have it execute.  OUTPUT just means output.  It doesn't mean "run".

The only way to get CF code to be executed by CF is to follow normal channels:
* request a template;
* include a template;
* call a template as a custom tag or CFMODULE;
* call a method in a CFC;
* any others?  ANyway, you get the point.

So if you have code that you create dynamically and want to execute... you need to write it to a file and then call it via the most appropriate of those mechanisms.  Be warned though: running dynamic code like this has a fair overhead, as the code needs to be compiled before it's run, and compilation is not the fastest process in the scheme of things.  The "best" thing to do here is to try to write and compile the file before it's needed, and only re-write the file it it needs updatng.  Don't re-do it every request.  But, ideally, don't do this sort of thing at all.  One can usually approach things a different way.

Comment: +1 for this. Running dynamically generated code will most probably cripple your system in the future, and worse of all, you will have no idea where the overhead is coming from, since you'll have no culprit to look at. In most cases you'll be able to get away by just slightly re-jigging your business rules.

Comment: Coyne's answer is correct, my tests on his solution yesterday were flawed. If you include a cfimport within the same context of the cfsavecontent call, the customtag will be evaluated and its contents will be saved to the variable specified in the 'variable' attribute, which can then be output.

Comment: Sorry Shawn... Sean's not answering the question that's actually been asked (see my comment on the answer marked as "correct").  Either that or the question needs rewording.

Comment: I agree in part that he described the saving correctly, just not the output of the executed content--I voted his answer up and mine down because of my original mishandling of the question. It may now be a question of 'what defines executed content'.