# Processing ColdFusion variables which reside inside a database table

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

One of my table is saving an HTML form which contains ColdFusion variables. In my code I am querying this table and need to display this form in the front end. But while displaying I am getting the ColdFusion variable names instead of the values of the variables.

## **HTML Form saved in the db table:**

```
<form action="" name="ci_entry_form" id="ci_entry_form" method="post">
<table width="100%" height="100%" border="0">
<tr>
<td align="right"><b style="color:red">*</b>&nbsp;<label class="pop_up_letter_font">G/L # &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:</label></td>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input class="pop_up_textbox" type="text" name="gl_number_text" id="gl_number_text" maxlength="21" value="#ARGUMENTS.chkDetails.GL_ACCT_NBR#" required/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<select class="pop_up_dd" name="gl_number_drop" id="gl_number_drop" onChange="enableDisableGL()">
<option value="">---Select---</option>
<option value="new">Enter a new G/L number</option>
<cfoutput query="glNumbers">
<option value="#glNumbers.GL_ACCT_NBR#">#glNumbers.GL_ACCT_NBR#</option>
</cfoutput>
</select>           
</td>        
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

## Method (cffunction) contains below code to query this html form from db table and return the html form.

```
<cfquery name="qry_getTemplate" datasource="#APPLICATION.dsn#">
select FORM_TXT from HTML_FORMS where REQ_ID = 172
</cfquery>  

<cfsavecontent variable="form_content">
<cfoutput>#qry_getTemplate.FORM_TXT #</cfoutput>
</cfsavecontent>
```

But when I dump the cfcontent variable `form_content` I am getting the HTML Form without processing the coldfusion variables `#ARGUMENTS.chkDetails.GL_ACCT_NBR#`, `#glNumbers.GL_ACCT_NBR#`.

Am I missing something? Can any one help me out resolve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I force evaluation of a cfif stored in a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4494166/how-do-i-force-evaluation-of-a-cfif-stored-in-a-string)

Answer (score 2):

I'm *pretty sure* if you searched this site or via Google a bit you could have found the answer to this already posted somewhere, given it comes up all the time (about once every 3-4 months).

You can't output CFML and somehow hope that it will execute.

I've summarised the CFML request / compile / response process on my blog: "[The ColdFusion request/response process](http://cfmlblog.adamcameron.me/2012/10/the-coldfusion-requestresponse-process.html#notexecuted)".

Bottom line: CFML source code needs to be loaded from the file system *at compile time* not at runtime. So your code needs to be in the file system when you want it to execute, not in the DB or in a variable.

You can write the code to file and then include it, though. This is detailed in that blog article.